# How to get the list of employees from specific LDAP group from MarkLogic XQuery?

Tags: ldap, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

How can I get the list of employees from specific LDAP group using MarkLogic XQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`xdmp:ldap-search()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:ldap-search) method to search for users that belong to the specified group.

Something like this:

```
xdmp:ldap-search(
  "(&(objectCategory=user)(memberOf=cn=MyCustomGroup))",
  <options xmlns="xdmp:ldap">
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
    <server-uri>ldap://dc1.mltest1.local:389</server-uri>
    <search-base>CN=Users,DC=MLTEST1,DC=LOCAL</search-base>
  </options>)
```